# SagePay Notification Blank

Tags: php, post, opayo

I have a problem that I'm hoping someone out there is going to be able to help me with, as SagePay support has been as helpful as a chocolate teapot. I have a bespoke e-commerce solution with SagePay Server Integration, some running v2.23 others v3.00. We have had a couple of websites suddenly stop working.

The Notification from SagePay is blank, completely and utterly empty. There is no post data available on either of the two websites. However we have two other websites where nothing else is wrong, everything is working fine.

The only difference between the 4 sites is the version, which necessitated some minor changes in what is sent to SagePay, and where they are hosted. The two working sites are hosted with HeartInternet, whereas the two that don't work are hosted with different hosts, one with 123reg and one with an unknown American host.

SagePay have sent me their logs for a couple of transactions, both show the Notification data present, so as far as they are concerned they are sending it to me fine and it's a server issue. I'm not even sure where to begin debuging this.

Not sure if it's relevant but I've added in the start of our Notification method:

```
public function Notify() {

    $this->Load();
    define('LOG_FILE', ROOT_LIB . 'sagepaylog-v2.23.txt');
    error_log(date('c') . " NEW NOTIFICATION" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    $input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $query = $response = array();
    $exp = explode('&', $input);
    foreach($exp as $keyVal) {
        $e = explode('=', $keyVal, 2);
        $response[$e[0]] = urldecode($e[1]);
    }
    /* Comment out the above code and uncomment below when testing using POSTMAN.
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
        $response[$key] = $val;
    }*/

    error_log("Notification Post Data" . PHP_EOL . "-------------------------" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    foreach($response as $key => $val) {
        error_log("$key: $val" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }

    //We record the transaction during the initial registration. We need to load the details of that transaction, and of the order for the specified order ID, and make sure they match the details sent to us by SagePay.
    $valid = FALSE;
    $orders = $this->glob->order->LoadOrderHistory("WHERE ordId = " . (int)$response['VendorTxCode'], TRUE);
    if(count($orders)) {
        $order = $orders[$response['VendorTxCode']];
    } else {
        $order = new Order($this->glob);
    }
    $transaction = new Transaction($this->glob, $order->txnId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was caused by an htaccess redirecting non-www to www, and the notification URL didn't include a www. This was fixed by checking the URL and adding a www in front if there wasn't already one.